# Get-ADComputer returns NULL when filtering by IPv4Address

Tags: powershell

I was trying to list computers in my network and identify which are in Domain and which aren't.

Here's an excerpt from the code:

```
$ipName ="10.0.0.$i"
$myPC = $NULL
$myPC = Get-ADComputer -property * -filter {IPv4Address -eq $ipName}
```

But most of the time it returns nothing(though with some IPs it works just as it should), even though if I filter by computer name I get that very computer with same IPv4Address property.

So for example

```
 Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {IPv4Address -eq "10.0.0.138"}
```

returns $NULL,
but at the same time

```
Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {Name -eq "KNP"}
```

returns all properties, including

```
 IPv4Address        : 10.0.0.138
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first ensure that it's matching like you think by using Where-Object.

```
Get-ADComputer -Properties * -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.IPv4Address -eq '10.0.0.138'}
```

If that brings back the computers you are expecting, something's going on with the AD provider's search syntax. The -Filter parameter for various cmdlets uses different providers. In this case, it's Active Directory.

If you look at the help for the filter itself, it has a lot of useful information as to how to construct filters.

```
get-help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter
```

Comment: This method works even though it's noticeably slower. Luckily network itself isn't too big.